# How to disable and enable Sonar configuration for a jenkins job?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

**Background :**

I am looking for a way to disable and enable Sonar configuration for some specific Jenkins build jobs. I wrote a groovy script which will remove the Sonar configuration for the particular job. But My requirement is to disable and enable the sonar configuration. Is it possible to do the same? If so, How?

**Groovy Script :**

```
import java.util.*
import hudson.model.*
import hudson.maven.*
import hudson.maven.reporters.*
import hudson.matrix.*
import hudson.tasks.*
import com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.customtools.* 
import com.synopsys.arc.jenkinsci.plugins.customtools.multiconfig.*
import com.synopsys.arc.jenkinsci.plugins.customtools.versions.*
import hudson.util.*

hudson.model.Hudson.instance.items.findAll{job -> job.isBuildable()}.each {
job ->

   if (job.name.contains("SonarVerification-Groovy")) {
   println "---------------------------------------------"
   println(job.name)
   sonar = job.publishersList.get(hudson.plugins.sonar.SonarPublisher.class)
   println sonar
   if(sonar){
       println "Sonar instance present"
       job.publishersList.remove(hudson.plugins.sonar.SonarPublisher.class)
       job.save()
   }else{
       println "Sonar instance not present" 
   }
  }
 }
```

I know we can disable Sonar plugin itself in manage Jenkins. But I need to disable the Sonar configuration at Jenkins job level.

Answer (score 0):

Set a build parameter with boolean value.

ONly run sonar if the parameter equals True.

You can set the parameter with a default value to always run sonar except if parameter equal false or the opposite.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But as I mentioned in the question I need to disable the Sonar Configuration for multiple jobs. It will be a huge effort to go and add parameter and conditions steps to disable the sonar. But is there is any plugin or groovy script that I can go with ?